# How do I convert a set to an interger in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a random 4 digit number in which none of the digits are repeated.

```
 import random

 sets = random.sample(range(0,9), 4)
```

This generates a random set of 4 digits but I want this as an integer. how do I do that?

Comment: Note: `range(0, 9)` excludes `9`.

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming OP meant all the digits)
Instead of using numbers and have to manipulate to `str` and back to `int`, just start with ascii digits:

```
>>> import string
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.digits, 4))
'4561'
```

You can convert to `int()` if necessary.
It's unclear what the OP intends to do if the first digit is `0`.

For a purely numerical approach you can use `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> import functools as ft
>>> ft.reduce(lambda s, d: 10*s + d, random.sample(range(10), 4))
2945
```

Comment: This actually answers the full question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting each digit to a string, joining them, and casting them as an integer.

```
int("".join(map(str,random.sample(range(0,9),4))))
```

Comment: Excellent one-liner

Answer (score 1):

if you need to generate 4 digit number, just for knowledge purpose use.

As suggested by AChampion this solution can contain duplicates

> > > from random import randint
> > >       randint(1000, 9999)

Use bernie Solution to generate a random 4 digit number in which none of the digits are repeated.

```
int("".join(map(str,random.sample(range(0,9),4))))
```

Comment: @bernie, thanks for the edit!!

Comment: Digits can be repeated with this solution.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for suggestion, edited the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want potentially infinite sequence of numbers with 4 unique digits (or any other condition – write your own)

```
import random


def numbers_gen(left_end, right_end):
    while True:
        yield random.randint(left_end, right_end)


def are_digits_unique(number):
    number_string = str(number)
    return list(set(number_string)) == list(number_string)


four_digits_numbers_gen = number_gen(left_end=1000,
                                     right_end=9999)
four_digits_numbers_with_unique_digits_gen = filter(are_digits_unique,
                                                    four_digits_numbers_gen)
```

Works only in Python 3 because [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns iterator-object (in Python 2.7 it returns `list`, more at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter))

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply with powers of 10:

```
sum(10**a*b for a, b in enumerate(reversed(sets)))
```

This works as long as the first element of `sets` is not zero.

Comment: Is `reversed()` necessary given they are just random digits?

Comment: @AChampion Depends on the nitty-gritty, doesn't it? For example, if upstream were to special case the first digit to be nonzero it would certainly be a nice touch to make sure it ends up on the left.

Comment: True, good point. Why do you claim this does not to work if the first element is `0`. Given you are reversing it, should give `XXX0` and if the last item is `0` it just gives a 3 digit number (implied `0`)

Comment: @AChampion Hm, doesn't it construct the number lsd and therefore rightmost first? I think I even tested it. -- Very commendable Horner scheme in your answer, btw.

Comment: Sorry, you are right `3` digit result occurs on first digit `0`. Unclear what the OP intends to do with first digit `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import random
my_set = set()
while len(my_set) < 4:
    x = random.choice(range(0,9))
    my_set.add(x)
my_num = int("".join(map(str, my_set)))
```

Comment: Why reimplement `random.sample()`?

Comment: You're right, no need. I got confused about sample selecting unique elements. But now I know!

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
int("".join(random.sample("0123456789",4)))
```